# Get the cookie from an HTTP request header

Tags: javascript, http

On Google Chrome, when I look at the HTTP request headers under the "Network" tab using the chrome console, it provides me the following request headers:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=nlbupfbt32jda1tziep4p21r; .ASPXAUTH=8C94786DD4A3C03C5548973E04A76FF554F38D6EB74E0B006AB3C3F72684E94DC0469E28D22E4BBFA069B82B1CCFB4203627D998990C6C96897DDBB0F611809175D5F06F015604082481F0079AE48DAB7974F3D63242055BEC75F707C545666C67B7C9D9E53F7531020235881E9DA4F3C26FD02B0ED0971D02C64DFE96F67C745119F44BBC9E46DC2CEF61D639EA01B9
... more headers ...
```

What I am trying to get is the data under Cookie. I have tried `document.cookie` but it returns an empty string. How can I grab that cookie information?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`document.cookies` returns nothing because the cookie is almost certainly marked with the [*HttpOnly*](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) attribute.

The presence of this attribute tells the browser to disallow access to the cookie value via `document.cookie`.

This is a security measure to prevent against [*session hijacking*](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack) via [*cross-site scripting*](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) mostly.

Comment: Is there anyway then to know the cookie being used by the browser session using javascript? For example, how are hackers able to spoof requests by guessing the correct cookie. Aren't they using javascript too?

Comment: Unfortunately not all websites use this attribute which makes them vulnerable. Not to mention some systems generate predictable or insecure session IDs which are susceptible to brute-force tactics. It is also possible to attain a session cookie via a [_man-in-the-middle attack_](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-middle_attack) if the website does not use a secure connection. Session cookies can also be stolen via malware or someone with physical access to the computer :(.

Comment: @Donato Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

If the cookie was set with the http-only flag, you can't read it using JavaScript - this is a security measure to prevent session hijacking and should be set for any surrogate identifier including session cookies.

Comment: Is there any other way to get the cookie. Maybe an ajax request and somehow get in the response header?

Comment: Try it. If it works at all, then the result will likely be browser dependent. If you need an authentication token available to Javascript, then turn off the HTTP-Only flag on the cookie or use a different identifier - and suffer the consequences.